# Selecting ID from url returns NULL data

Tags: php, mysqli

I have functions page and details.php.

**Functions Page:**

```
function getDetails(){
    $con = new Core();
    $con->connect();    
    $param = $_GET['autoid'];
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM auto WHERE autoid=?';
    $stmt = $con->myconn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $param);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

**home.php:**

```
    <?php
        $details = new Details();
        $result = $details->showDetails();
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $id=$row['autoid'];
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo '<a href="details.php?autoid='.$id.'">
            <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($row['foto'] ).'"/></a>'; ?> 
        </td>
    </tr>
   <?php }
    mysqli_free_result($result); 
    ?>
```

**details.php:**

```
$details = new Details();
$result = $details->getDetails();
var_dump($result);
```

When I'm in my home.php I press on a picture and get redirected to details.php.
When I'm there I got the ID in my url and then I var dump but get returned a NULL.

And because of that my code in details.php doesn't work :

```
while ($row = $result) {

    <tr>
               <td><?php echo $row['merk']; ?> </td>
```

I'd really appreciate some help. Since I can't figure how to let it work. 
So basically I don't get anything shown on the details page. Besides a NULL of the var_dump.

Comment: What is ` $stmt->bind_param("i", $param);` Isn't **"i"** replaced with **"?"** ?

Comment: @PraveenKumar **i** is for Int

Comment: Try my answer and let me know if that is working for you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're executing showDetails and not getDetails? 
Also your function getDetails doesn't return anything. I suspect you have to execute getDetails and put a return in the function to make it work.

Functions Page:

```
function getDetails(){
    $con = new Core();
    $con->connect();    
    $param = $_GET['autoid'];
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM auto WHERE autoid=?';
    if(!($stmt = $con->myconn->prepare($sql))) {
        echo "Prepare failed: (" . $con->myconn->errno . ") " . $con->myconn->error;
    }
    if(!($stmt->bind_param("i", $param))) {
        echo "Binding parameters failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
    }
    if(!($stmt->execute()) {
        echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
    }
    if(!($result = $stmt->get_result()) {
        echo "Getting result set failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
    }
    return $result; // added return here
}
```

home.php:

```
$details = new Details();
    $result = $details->getDetails(); //Changed this to getDetails
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $id=$row['autoid'];
    ?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo '<a href="details.php?autoid='.$id.'"><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($row['foto'] ).'"/></a>'; ?> </td>
    </tr>
```

`execute()` only returns a Boolean on whether it was successful or not. you need to use `get_result()` to get the actual results of the query

Comment: Thank you for your assitance. So far I've edited my problem with your code. Yet I get the error: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given. No success so far.

Comment: Oh and The home.php is working fine. The problem lays in my Details.php.

Comment: this means that you're query has encountered an error and therefore returned false instead of results

Comment: I added an if to check the error that occurs in the execute, this should help you figure out what is going wrong. also check this link on how to report mysql errors in each stage of building the statement

Comment: forgot to add the link ;') http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php
did you manage to get an error message? you can also echo the query and the variables and just try it in the database first.

Comment: There was no Error message besides the "boolean given". When I tested the query in the database it worked aswell. Any further tips?

Comment: the boolean given means that the $result is false which means that somewhere along the line in preparing and executing the query it goes wrong. I'm trusting you're setting up the connection correctly in your core object in that case all that is left is to put checks on the prepare, the bind param and the execute. I'll edit my answer to show this

Comment: read up on prepared statements so you understand what does this code do, it will explain why doesn't this code work http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Yes my connection works properly. I'm 100% sure about that. Because the function showDetails works aswell. With the same setup. Anyways thanks for helping me out! I'll be waiting for the edit.

Comment: @YourCommonSense may i ask why the downvote? assuming it was you. i'm trying to figure it out with him and i'll edit my answer once we do. also i already gave him that link.

Comment: A downvote is simply because you wrote a code that will never work.

Comment: @YourCommonSense What would be the correct fix for it? Can you give some tips what's wrong with it? Btw, I get a prepare failed: (0) now. I'm trying to fix that.

Comment: I fixed that problem, Still got the problem of: " mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given".

Comment: @YourCommonSense what part of this will never work? your way of reviewing stuff more often than not seems to be being mean to people trying to help, instead of giving constructive criticism. (Not just based on this case) And I don't really see how that helps anyone in getting better, not me nor the person asking for help.

Comment: I've been lurking around aswell for a longtime and I totally agree with @Jester with his statement. I've almost if not never seen a positive constructive answer to someone's question.

Comment: @T.Korkmazyigit can you check whether an echo in that function will ever be visible to you? if you just echo something random does it show?

Comment: what about if you do a print_r($result) before you return it? maybe add echo "<pre>" in front and "</pre>" behind to make it more readable

Comment: print_r echo's : 1. var_dump echo's bool(true)

Comment: oh stupid me execute works fine you just need extract the results as well, i'll edit my answer

Comment: no problem, happy to help! ^^ i'll edit my answer to formulate the correct solution a bit better. Good luck with the rest of your project. and check out the link ;) it was in there :p